# Answer votes and upvotes pluralisation are wrong in activity tab when there's only one vote

Tags: bug, activity-tab

If you cast a single answer vote and a single question vote then the summary tab in your profile will look something like this:

[image: Votes cast]

Below is as close as I can make that image as text...

| Votes cast |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 downvotes | 1 question vote | 1 answer votes |

See how question vote has the correct pluralisation but answer votes does not. This [user's profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/8604852/noob?tab=topactivity) has two votes.

If you [only cast a single vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366634/v-v?tab=topactivity) then upvotes (or presumably downvotes) is wrong.

[image: single vote cast]

Looks something like this as text...

| Votes cast |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1 upvotes | 1 answer votes |

Comment: Sheesh. Did the Joker build this? If you're going to do it wrong then do it consistently wrong, so I'd settle for the "1 question vote" to be changed to be "1 question votes". At least it would be all according to plan. But this is chaos.